# Web service integration with Java, are their any issues with types?

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf

If a web service is written in .net using WCF, can a java client use it without an issue or are there problems with returning specific types/collections like List ?

Would using guava (which I believe is a set of types) help?

Comment: I would recommend to read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on what binding you are using on the WCF service. You should expose an interoperable binding endpoind such as `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding` so that a Java client can consume it. If you use a proprietary binding such as `netTcpBinding` only .NET clients can consume your service.

So I invite you to go ahead and read about the [different available bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) that you could use in WCF.

Comment: someone had mentioned to me you can't you List, just wanted to verify that.

Comment: @codecompleting, you can use lists, it's just that it is not recommended. If you use an interoperable binding WCF will anyway expose those lists as standard types such as arrays in the WSDL so that your service is compatible with different clients.